# Buffer over flow exploit not working as intended

Tags: c++, python-3.x, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am writing a simple buffer overflow exploit for educational purposes in c++, the exploit code is running perfectly because when I supply the 612 "A" chars with the return address it outputs "welcome!" to gdb
and then crashes, but when i try to supply the shellcode to make a new user it simply does not work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buff[600];
    scanf('%s', buff);
    printf("Welcome! %s \n");
    return 0;
}
```

this is the c++ exploit code that i wrote my self to exploit
i found the offset to be 612 and got the return address "0x81f0e483"

```
EIP = struct.pack("I", 0x81f0e483)
```

when i open a cmd and type

```
python print ("A"*612+EIP)
```

then pipe the output to the compiled c++ executable everything works perfectly i get "Welcome!" a couple of time then the program crashes

now when i use a any shellcode from http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-874.php
for windows machines for example :"Add Admin User Shellcode (194 bytes)"
i get an error or the program just crashes

to clarify my buffer is 612 and the shellcode is 194 i am left with 418 bytes 200 bytes for the nope slide and 100 for the padding i am left with 18 bytes for the return address 
the output is (padding +nope_slide +shellcode +EIP)
the output gets piped to the vulnerable c++ executeable but i do not get a new user
and i tried making custom shellcodes with msfvenom but was not lucky got the same result

what am i doing wrong

Comment: `scanf('%s', buff);` should result in a build error. Please make sure that the [mcve] you show doesn't contain any other unrelated problems or errors. And copy-paste the actual code you have, don't rewrite it into the question.

Comment: And `printf("Welcome! $s \n");` doesn't do what you apparently expect it to do. Perhaps you should refresh some basic C knowledge (there's nothing C++ specific in your code). There's also some other "weird" things about your code that doesn't really match up, like the Windows-specific `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` macro (put in the wrong place anyway) and the POSIX (Unix) only `<unistd.h>` header.